# EditorConfig - Convert tabs to spaces in SQL files transparently

Tags: sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, format, editorconfig

I have a set of `.sql` scripts in a project I am working on which currently contain a mix of tabs and spaces for indentation. I would like to find a method which will *automatically and transparently* convert these tabs to spaces *on file save*. It would be great if the auto formatting worked in both VS Code AND Visual Studio.

I have tried an EditorConfig (`.editorconfig`) file like so:

```
root = true

# Enforce 4 space indenting and NO tabs in SQL script files
[*.sql]
end_of_line = crlf
indent_size = 4
indent_style = space
```

but it doesnt seem to work. Even when I try the manual "Format Document" option in either VS Code or Visual Studio, nothing happens. I also tried to set up the Prettier VS Code extension but I couldnt get that to work either.

First of all, is this possible using EditorConfig and if not, how can I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options, and the "best" one depends on the dialect of SQL you want to use.

1. RedGate SQL Toolbelt and SQL Toolbelt Essentials contains a command line verison of RedGate SQL Prompt that will format your code for you. See: https://documentation.red-gate.com/sp/features-available-only-in-sql-toolbelt-essentials-and-sql-toolbelt/bulk-operations/bulk-operations-via-the-command-line for instructions on using `SqlPrompt.Format.CommandLine.exe`
2. [vscode-sql-formatter](https://github.com/kufii/vscode-sql-formatter) plug-in, which handles the following dialect options:

   1. sql: Standard SQL. **Defaults to sql.**
   2. n1ql: Couchbase N1QL
   3. db2: IBM DB2
   4. pl/sql: Oracle PL/SQL).

SQL Server Management Studio doesn't support .editorconfig, and t[he only feature request for Microsoft Azure Data Studio to support .editorconfig was closed](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/t-sql-editor-does-not-follow-editorconfig-and-repl-10/305236) by Microsoft saying it was too low a priority for them to even bother reviewing. I think that transparency is great, since they're being brutally honest with customers that providing free SQL formatting tools isn't a priority for them.